Solving Create Space Time Cube Error in ArcGIS Pro
This is the error I keep getting when I try to use "Create Space Time Cube from Defined Locations" in ArcGIS Pro. My study area is a gridded (30x30m per square) area, and each square has the value I want to assess through time (10 years)

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2259, in
execute   File "c:\program
files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPanelObject.py", line
278, in obtainData
self.__obtainDataRowsJoinTable()   File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPanelObject.py", line
579, in __obtainDataRowsJoinTable
self.__binData()   File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPanelObject.py", line
836, in __binData
orderIDs = [self.master2Order[i] for i in masterIDs]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\program
files\arcgis\pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSPanelObject.py", line
836, in 
orderIDs = [self.master2Order[i] for i in masterIDs]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^ KeyError: '37'

I'm thinking it's something to do with the way I link my shapefile to my related table. The first value in the related table is a 37 which should correspond to a feature (a grid shape) in my study area.
My dates (in 01/01/2023) format are in "date" format. The column I want to connect to the shapefile (of grids) has "number" format; I also tested and changed it to "text" format but both don't work. I have around 12,000 data "squares" per year.

